# mongodb aggregation and sorting on moongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

There are two mongoose schema

```
    const bookModel =  new Schema({
    title : String,
    content: String,
    author:{
        id:{
            type: ObjectId,
        },
        name:{
            type: String,
        }
    }
})


const commentModel = new Schema({
    text :String,
    bookid :{ { type : ObjectId , required : true } },
    inEnglish:{
        type: Boolean,
        default:false
    }
})
```

how can we write a mongo query to find the famous books on the basis of number of comments

so, write find query to sort the books on the basis of number of comments(in which inEnglish is set to true) on a particular books.

JSON is stored in mongo as:

Book JSON-

```
{
    "_id" :ObjectId(58368df330391521247f6aeb),
    "title": "Dan Brown",
    "content": "COntent of the book" 
}
```

Comment JSON-

```
{
        "_id" :ObjectId(24568df330391765434f6fgh),
        "text":"Nice Book",
        "bookid":"58368df330391521247f6aeb",
        inEnglish: true

}
```

Comment: did you wrote any query yet ? i mean have you tried something and stuck somewhere ?

Comment: `db.comments.aggregate(
{ $match : { inEnglish : true} },
{$group : { _id: {bookId :"$bookId"}, "totalC":{$sum:1}}},
{$sort : {"_id.totalC":1}})`
i have tried this but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

i created a small collection

```
>db.comments.find()

{"_id" : ObjectId("58387da2a32c4b96e67ec6b4"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aeb", "inEnglish" : true }
{"_id" : ObjectId("58387da8a32c4b96e67ec6b5"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aeb", "inEnglish" : true }
{"_id" : ObjectId("58387da9a32c4b96e67ec6b6"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aeb", "inEnglish" : true }
{"_id" : ObjectId("58387da9a32c4b96e67ec6b7"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aeb", "inEnglish" : true }
{"_id" : ObjectId("58387db0a32c4b96e67ec6b8"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aec", "inEnglish" : true }
{"_id" : ObjectId("58387db2a32c4b96e67ec6b9"), "text" : "Nice Book", "bookid" : "58368df330391521247f6aec", "inEnglish" : true }
```

now to get book the comments, i run the following

```
db.comments.aggregate(
    {$group : {_id : "$bookid", "count" : {$sum : 1}}},
    {$sort : {"count" : -1}},
    {$limit : 1}
)
```

basically what i am doing is group by the book ID and get the count.

my output

```
{ "_id" : "58368df330391521247f6aeb", "count" : 4 }
```

> **note:** i am not doing filters using inEnglish:true. if you want you can include that in the query,

Comment: With above query, you will able to find  only book id. Try this query to get detail of book  

**db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : "$bookid", "count" : {$sum : 1}}},
    {$sort : {"count" : -1}},
    {$limit : 1},
    { $lookup : { from : "books", localField : "_id", foreignField : "_id", as : "books" } }
])**

Comment: which one are you referring to the one i gave or the one Anish gave ?